# hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings being ignored by glassfish?

Tags: java, hibernate, glassfish

I am using Hibernate 3.6.9final with Glassfish 3.1.1.

When I start my application I get the following warning: "Hibernate does not support `SequenceGenerator.initialValue()` unless `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings`".

According to the docs I can turn on/off support for the new sequence generator by enabling/disabling the `hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings` value. In my `persistence.xml` I set the following option in the properties:

```
<property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
```

This seems to be completely ignored and I still get the warnings. Is this a setting that cannot be set in persistence.xml? I do not use an AnnotationConfiguration within the application nor do i have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` or an `hbm.xml`.

suggestions?

Comment: This seems to be a common issue. I have set this property in the `.cfg.xml` file of a command line application and it is also being ignored.